# Use SSH config file with Putty

Tags: authentication, windows, ssh, configuration

I'm using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (a Git GUI) which uses [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) as SSH client. I need to push some code into a repository for which I need to tunnel through SSH to do so. The trouble is, the repository and SSH authentication server are on separate servers. Hence, I need to login to one server and then push to another one.

I was given the following `config` file but I don't know how to use it with PuTTY:

```
Host login
HostName login.nets.*******.**

Host zeus
HostName zeus.nets.*******.**
ProxyCommand ssh login nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
#ProxyCommand ssh login -W %h:%p
ForwardAgent yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PuTTY does not store its configuration [in a file](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-disksettings). However, PuTTY can use a "proxy command", as described [here](http://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/).

In your case, the example config file shows that there should be two encapsulated SSH connections:

- The outer SSH is done to host `login.nets.***`. When that connection is done, the command `nc` is run on that host: it basically forwards data bytes to port 22 on the inner host `zeus.nets.***`.
- The inner SSH is done again from your machine, to host `zeus.nets.***`, with all data bytes sent through the outer SSH.

In the `ProxyCommand` option, the `ssh login` part is the invocation of the outer SSH when the user (or your GUI application) tries to connect to "zeus". It is not obvious whether `PuTTY` itself can be invoked that way: there *is* a [command line](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7) but you also need the "inner PuTTY" to forward all its bytes to the "outer PuTTY", and it is unclear whether that "outer PuTTY" will accept the bytes on its "standard input" (Windows is not Unix, and, moreover, PuTTY does not expect to run in a terminal or on raw bytes; it more tries to open its own window).

**Possible alternatives:**

- Try to use [port forwarding](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.5). In that case, you manually start a PuTTY to `login.nets.***`, with a port forwarding from local port 5000 (that's an example) to remote host `zeus.nets.***` and remote port 22. Then you configure your GUI to talk (with PuTTY) to `localhost` on port 5000. When the GUI launches the PuTTY which connects to `localhost` on port 5000, the other PuTTY (the one you started manually) forwards the bytes to host `login.nets.***` with instructions to open a connection from that host to `zeus.nets.***` on port 22.

  This may or may not work, depending on the configuration of the SSH server on `login.nets.***` (support for such tunnels can be enabled or disabled by the sysadmin).
- Use a more Unix-like SSH client, e.g. through [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Since this is *the* usual [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), it will be able to read and use the provided SSH configuration file, and do the nested invocation. Of course, there is no guarantee that your "SourceTree" application can be configured to use such a SSH client.